# Adding FreeRTOS libraries to Energia IDE

Tags: c, texas-instruments, energia

Im trying to add FreeRTOS libraries to Energia IDE specifically for the Texas Instruments CS3220SF board. I already have integrated hardware using Energia libraries and want to use FreeRTOS functionality, I dont want to use TI-RTOS.

I setup the project in CCS IDE using this guide: https://www.freertos.org/TI_CC3220_SimpleLink_FreeRTOS_Demo.html

First I added all FreeRTOS source (timers.h,task.h,etc..) & required FreeRTOSConfig.h in same source folder as my project.

After compiling in Energia IDE i get this error:

```
C:\Users\Fsydn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDJlHYY.s: Assembler messages:

C:\Users\Fsydn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDJlHYY.s:468: Error: selected processor does not support `vstmdbeq r0!,{s16-s31}' in Thumb mode

C:\Users\Fsydn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDJlHYY.s:470: Error: instruction not allowed in IT block -- `mrs r1,control'

C:\Users\Fsydn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDJlHYY.s:495: Error: selected processor does not support `vldmiaeq r0!,{s16-s31}' in Thumb mode

C:\Users\Fsydn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDJlHYY.s:497: Error: instruction not allowed in IT block -- `msr psp,r0'

exit status 1
Error compiling for board CC3220SF-LAUNCHXL (80MHz).
```

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining that you are compiling floating point instructions but the command line options passed to the compiler have not stated that the target device has a floating point unit.  Either you are building the wrong [FreeRTOS source files](https://www.freertos.org/a00017.html) (build FreeRTOS/Source/[compiler]/ARM_CM3 if Cortex-M3 or M4 without floating point, or FreeRTOS/Source/[compiler]/ARM_CM4F if Cortex-M4 with floating point), or your compiler command line is wrong.